# Action bar for Android 2.1

Tags: android, user-interface

Is there action bar for Android Level 7 or something else that I can use as action bar?
I need to build an app which is using action bar for Android 2.1

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is the best for API 7+.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JohanNilsson has actually created a `ActionBar` library which is available on **GitHub**.

[Direct link.](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar)

Comment: One down vote, I can clarify that I have no connections to johannilsson than I have used the actionbar.

Comment: +1, Good answer, I see no reason to get a downvote for this. Helped me to find a nice library.

Answer (score 12):

[here you go](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html). The **officle android** article is called: ActionBarCompat - Action Bar Compatibility. (just in case the link wont work for ever)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you should try this open source project http://actionbarsherlock.com , you will find it's full definition on this website
In the newest version it will have support for features provided by ICS.

Answer (score 2):

```
TypedArray a = mActivity.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme, new int[] {
    R.attr.actionbarCompatItemHomeStyle,
    R.attr.actionbarCompatItemStyle
});
int actionbarCompatItemHomeStyle = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
int actionbarCompatItemStyle = a.getResourceId(1, 0);
ImageButton actionButton = new ImageButton(mActivity, null,
    itemId == android.R.id.home ? actionbarCompatItemHomeStyle : actionbarCompatItemStyle
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of action bar in pre-Honeycomb versions of Android is the options menu, accessible under Menu button.

Answer (score 0):

In July 2013 Google added action bar compatibility back to 2.1 (7+) in New `"v7 appcompat library"`
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html