# how to insert actionbar tabs in each activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I am new to android and I am trying to develop an android application in which I have used `actionbar` tabs at the bottom of the screen,from where if any icon is clicked then the related activity is opened,but every time I have to come back on the main activity to select another icon to start another activity,instead of that I want my actionbar tabs on each activity so that I could select the icons irrespective of the current activity.so please help,at lest give some clue so that i could find my way. thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623749/action-bar-for-android-2-1

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an `Activity`, say `ParentActivity` that has your actionbar with desired click events.  Then you would `extend` it for each final `Activity`, so all of them have the same actionbar and the same functionality.
If you have problem in about creating actionbar,you can see this page:
[edumobile.org](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what hasanghaforian has suggested, or if you want to avoid extending ParentActivity  for whatever reason (let's say your activities extend Activity, ListActivity and PreferenceActivity) you can create a class MyCoolMenuInflator, which has methods onOptionsMenuCreated() and onOptionsMenuItemSelected(), which you can call from respective methods of all your activities. This is more flexible, since you can do extra things, like dynamically add or remove action bar items.